# How to Stack a ZStack on a NavigationView?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a view (`NoticeView`) that's supposed to act like an `Alert`, but without obstructing the user's view. It transitions and leaves from the top of the screen.

```swift
struct NoticeView<Content: View>: View {
    private let content: Content

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            content.padding()
                .background(Color.white)
                .cornerRadius(32)
                .shadow(radius: 10)

            Spacer()
        }.transition(.move(edge: .top))
        .animation(Animation.default.speed(0.33))
    }

    init(@ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
        self.content = content()
    }
}
```

In the main view (a playground project here), I use a `ZStack` so the view can animate on top of other views and leave without disturbing other views.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isPresenting = false

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            if isPresenting {
                NoticeView {
                    Link(destination: URL(string: "https://www.apple.com")!) {
                        Label("You must sign in to perform this action.", systemImage: "person.crop.circle.badge.plus")
                    }
                }.onAppear {
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5) {
                        isPresenting = false
                    }
                }
            }

            Button("Click") {
                isPresenting = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It ends up looking like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vR6Ix.jpg (which is what I want).

However, when using a `NavigationView`, the notice doesn't display correctly.

```swift
// Case #1: `NavigationView {...}` shows, but pressing Click does nothing.
ZStack {
  // `if isPresenting {...}`

  // `NavigationView {...}`
}

// Case #2: The button nor the alert is shown, but setting `isPresenting` to `true` by default causes it to slide in from the top left corner and transition out (due to default animations).
ZStack {
  NavigationView {
    // if isPresenting {...}

    // Button(...) {...}
  }
}

// Case #3: The button is shown and the alert shows when clicked, but it's not as high as it should be since it's inside the NavigationView. This also won't be ideal because I want alerts to be independent of the current view it's in (e.g. triggering the alert from the root view so it displays everywhere for 4-5 seconds).
NavigationView {
  ZStack {
    // if isPresenting {...}

    // Button(...) {...}
  }
}
```

To add fuel to the flames, I don't know if this will work great on other platforms like macOS and watchOS. How could I solve this problem? I wouldn't mind if there are other ways to implement this kind of alert where the user's view won't get obstructed that are more idiomatic.

Comment: You want me to write for you an answer how i do it?

Comment: Sure, that would be helpful :)

Comment: Yes, and it does work. It's not limited to links (it can be anything), but the issue here is the notification does not always display. Though, I may end up sticking with it and containing the notification to the view for it to work (switching from one view to another won't show the last alert).

Comment: Check is this helpful? if yes let me know i'll post the code or tell me what do i need to change and i'll do it :) imgur.com/a/B8Z4Wes

Comment: Welcome to SO. You mentioned "the notice doesn't display correctly" - please explain what exactly is not working. See also [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Here it is a quick code that I have created for another way to implement this kind of notification.

```
import SwiftUI

struct notificationViewTop: View {
    @State var showNotification = false
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            
            
            VStack {
                
                Link(destination: URL(string: "https://www.apple.com")!) {
                                        Label("You must sign in to perform this action.", systemImage: "person.crop.circle.badge.plus")
                                    }
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .frame(height: 60)
                    .background(Color.red)
                    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20, style: .continuous))
                    .padding()
                    .offset(y: showNotification ? 0 : -200)
                    .animation(.spring())
                
                
                Spacer()
                
                Button(action: {
                    self.showNotification = true
                    
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5) {
                        self.showNotification = false
                    }
                    
                }) {
                    Text("Show notification")
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
}

struct notificationViewTop_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        notificationViewTop()
    }
}
```

What I did is i created the notification container, and then I pushed it the top of the screen using `Spacer()`. Then to hide the notification I have used `offset()` to push it out of the screen borders.

After that i created state variable `@State var showNotification = false` to use it to show the notification and `animation(.spring())` to animate it on Show/Hide state.